# Approximate maxima of this exponential function which saturates after a certain point

Tags: calculus, approximation, maxima-minima

I have the following fucntion:
$$y=\frac{1}{C}(1-e^{-C(1-e^{-x})})$$

The term $C$ varies between $0<C<1$.

Some plots of the function are attached as images

[image]

Blue is for $C=1$, Yellow for $C=0.7$ and Green is for $C=0.5$

It can be seen that there is no abslute maxima, however the function saturates after a certain $x$.

Is there any way an approximate maxima expression involving $C$ can be deduced ?

Comment: Are you asking for $\lim_{x\to +\infty}y(x)$?

Comment: @Gary In a sense, yes. As you can see $y$ almost saturates after a certain $x$, so its value changes miniscully beyond this particular $x$. Can this limit be evaluated ?

Comment: Yes, pretty easily. Do you know that $e^{ - x}  \to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$? What does that give you for $y(x)$?

Comment: @Gary Appreciate this Gary, Now i can see it. The limit will evaluate to $\frac{1-e^{-C}}{C}$. I should hae looked at the graph of $e^{-x}$

Comment: Yes, that is the correct result.